# Finding tension in pulley system

Tags: physics, problem-solving

I'm struggling with part C of this question: https://isaacphysics.org/questions/ft_mech_stage1_q4_2018?board=y12ms2021_22_week15&stage=a_level

(acceleration of particle $R = 4.21$. Worked out in part B)

I tried drawing free-body diagrams for particles P, Q and R. I've also tried writing $F=ma$ for each particle.

I ended up with these 3 equations:

$T-mg=ma$ (P)

$0.45g-2.52=0.45a$ (R)

$0.05g-T=0.05a$ (Q)

I don't know where to go from here - I tried assuming that R and Q would have the same acceleration, and used the equations to work out tension $= 0.28~\text{N}$ (this was wrong).

It would be really helpful if someone could point me in the right direction or tell me where I'm going wrong. Thanks

(I'm doing A Level maths and physics if that helps)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: There is a good community for you: https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Hermis14 Thank you - I wasn't sure whether this was more maths or physics related

Comment: I think this question is suitable enough for this site because it is part of *maths* A Level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I got $a=4.2,\ $ not $a=4.21:$

$(b)\quad F=ma$ on particle $R\ $: $0.45 \times 9.8 - 2.52 = 0.45a,\ $ so $\ a = \frac{0.45 \times 9.8 - 2.52}{0.45} = 4.2\ $ ms$^{-2}.$

Secondly, your equation for $Q$ is not correct because particle $R$ is pulling particle $Q$ downward with a force of $2.52$N. You have left this out of your equation when you shouldn't have...

Finally, all you then have to do is to substitute $a=4.2\ $ into your equation for $Q$ and rearrange to get the value of $T.$

$(c)\quad F=ma\ $ on particle $Q:\ 2.52 + 0.05\times 9.8 - T = 0.05 \times 4.2 \implies T = 2.8$N.